# Page.ResolveClientUrl

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I am using `page.ResolveClientUrl` in my asp.net page like:

```
var handlerPage='<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Forms/Handlerimgs.ashx") %>';
```

but after running the application it not shows the url,it display like:

```
var handlerPage='';
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a control that is databound? if not <%# %> tags have no effect, try <%= %>